# NodeJS bug with promise.catch and console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, console.log

When running the following code, I get different results depending on if I have `console.log("fnError: ", fnError)` commented out or not.  This seems very off to me.

**How in the world is a call to `console.log` affecting my promises?**

```js
function run() {
    var fn = function(){
        throw new Error("incorrect message");
    };

    // returns a promise that should fail with
    // an error object whose .message is "correct message"
    var promisifiedFn = function(){
        return Promise.resolve()
            .then(fn)
            .catch((fnError) => {
                // commenting this out fixes things! //
                console.log("fnError: ", fnError);
                ///////////////////////////////////////

                fnError.message = "correct message";
                throw fnError;
            })
    }

    promisifiedFn().catch((e) => {
        console.log("caught error.message:", e.message);
        console.log("caught error:", e);
    });
}
run();
```

The above produces:

```
// fnError:  Error: incorrect message
//     at fn (/Users/sam/dev/ethereum/pennyeth/js/temp.js:18:9)
//     at <anonymous>
//     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
//     ...
// caught error.message: correct message
// caught error: Error: incorrect message
//     at fn (/Users/sam/dev/ethereum/pennyeth/js/temp.js:18:9)
//     at <anonymous>
//     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
//     ...
```

Notice "incorrect message" being logged.  And if you comment out `console.log("fnError: ", fnError)` you get this:

```
// caught error.message: correct message
// caught error: Error: correct message
//     at fn (/Users/sam/dev/ethereum/pennyeth/js/temp.js:18:9)
//     at <anonymous>
//     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
//     ....
```

Running node 8.0.0

Comment: Note:  In my actual application code, I'm _not_ logging the error before rethrowing it, and I still get this behavior.  Unfortunately I'm not able to figure out a minimal example of it.

Comment: This is bizarre. I tried it Chrome 59 and it does not have the same problem. But Node 7.9.0, Node 8.0.0, and Node 8.1.2 all have this behavior (or bug).

Comment: My only thought is that console.log is caching the Error object before rending to stdout. Notice that both "incorrect message" results are logging the same object.

Comment: There's still the problem with my application code, where I'm not even doing `console.log` and still getting the wrong error object.  I've resulted to throwing a new error, but that loses the original stacktrace.

Comment: Can do a `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(fnError, "message"))` please?

Comment: @Bergi `{ value: 'first', writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

Logging the error (which goes through `util.inspect` or `String` at least) does evaluate its `.stack` property. The stack string is not initialised when the error object is instantiated, but is built lazily to save memory. The stack trace will include the error's message, and when you change the `.message` property it will be reflected or not in the stack trace depending on whether that already had been created.

From [the V8 stack trace API description](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Stack-Trace-API#customizing-stack-traces):

> For efficiency stack traces are not formatted when they are captured but on demand, the first time the stack property is accessed.

and from [the official node `Error` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_stack):

> The string representing the stack trace is lazily generated when the error.stack property is **accessed**.

Comment: Why does Chrome have different behavior than Node.js? Is node making this optimization and chrome is not?

Comment: @styfle I haven't tried it yet, but I suspect the difference is only in `console.log` and not `error.stack`

Comment: @styfle I can reproduce it in Chrome when explicitly accessing `.stack`. But indeed, `console.log(e)` alone does show the updated message.

Comment: This actually makes me miss Java.. plus you can chain together Exceptions and never end up with this confusion.

Comment: @Bergi are there other events that cause `stack` to be built?  I'm getting the  same behavior even when not doing `console.log`, though I can't simplify it to an example yet.

Comment: @JS_Riddler "*Unlike Java where the stack trace of an exception is a structured value that allows inspection of the stack state, the stack property in V8 just holds a flat string containing the formatted stack trace; for no other reason than compatibility with other browsers.*". Afair, there have been efforts to standardise a structured stack trace API, they just haven't been implemented as there is no dire need for it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this "bug" with only 4 lines below.

```
var e = new Error('first');
console.log(e);
e.message = 'new';
console.log(e);
```

I tried it Chrome 59 and it does not have the same problem.

However Node 7.9.0, Node 8.0.0, and Node 8.1.2 all have this problem.

I reported as a bug on GitHub [#13832](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13832) so we will see what comes of it.

**Update 1**: To show this is not a timing issue, we can add `setTimeout` calls

```
var e = new Error('first');
console.log(e);
setTimeout(() => { e.message = 'new'; }, 1000);
setTimeout(() => console.log(e), 2000);
```

The problem persists even if we wait to call `console.log()` which makes me believe the output is cached.

**Update 2**: I got a response from the *mscdex* on GitHub:

> This is expected because what you're seeing is the stack trace, which includes the error message once it's generated. The stack trace is generated lazily and only once (for performance reasons), so that is why you see the same output both times.
>
> If you however change your code to output e.message, you will see the expected change in output.

Ultimately, both *mscdex* and *Bergi* are saying the root cause is lazy evaluation.

What you're doing is probably not a common scenario so I would avoid doing it in the future since it doesn't appear the node.js team will change this behavior.

Comment: I'm still getting this problem in my application code, which does something similar but does not do `console.log`, meaning I get the "old" error message.